# Trigger visual state from viewmodel (behavior)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to trigger a visual state with the help of the Behavior SDK. The current state of a Flyout (show/hide) should depend on the value of `FlyoutIsVisible` in the ViewModel. All bindings are fine and everything works as expected except for the animation. The flyout doesn't show up. When I trigger the visual states via the code behind it works. The `DataTriggerBehavior` works as well (e.g. invoke a command instead of the state action).

```
<interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding FlyoutIsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="True">
        <core:GoToStateAction StateName="ShowFlyout" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Flyout}" />
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
    <core:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding FlyoutIsVisible}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="False">
        <core:GoToStateAction StateName="HideFlyout" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Flyout}" />
    </core:DataTriggerBehavior>
</interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Visual States:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="ShowFlyout">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Flyout"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                            From="380" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.5" EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                            d:IsOptimized="True">
                    <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                    </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        ...
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Flyout:

```
<Border x:Name="Flyout">
    <Border.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="380" />
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    ...
</Border>
```

So I assume there's a problem with the scope/context of the visual states. I'm not sure where to place the visual states and the behavior. If both are inside the Flyout (and omitting the `TargetObject` attribute) I get an exception that says there are not visual states on the control. Otherwise (declared outside and with the attribute) simply nothing happens. So what's the right way to use the go-to-state behavior?

**Update:**

```
Page
-Grid
--Grid (Header)
--Grid (Content)
---Grid
----Some Element
----The Flyout
----Some Element
----Some Element
--VisualStateManager
--DataTriggerBehavior
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure is all OK. The problem that it doesn't work is because of this line.

```
TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Flyout}"
```

As soon as you have this in the `GoToStateAction`, it actually goes into this `Flyout` element (i.e. a `Border`) and tries to find a `VisualState` called **ShowFlyout**/**HideFlyout**. Of course it won't find it as these states are declared under the very top `Grid`.

Simply remove this piece of code and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Behavior` and the `VisualState` need to both be under the root element.

Comment: Hi Jerry, thanks for your help. But that didn't really work out. I've just updated the question with the structure of my page. The VisualStates (at their current place) are used from the code behind with events from the ViewModel (not nice, but functional).

Comment: Maybe there's some help here: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html